# Question about guest of hazrat A'isha R.A?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, shia-sunni, non-mahram, aisha

Aoa, a shia person asked me this question regarding the Hadith in Sahih Muslim, book of purifications narrates from alqamah and aswad, Hadith 566/288/668 depending upon the print you have . The question is that the Shi'a person was claiming that a stranger and non mahram man was staying with A'isha R.A in her house and thus claiming she was indecent (nauzubillah) . Could you please explain this Hadith in context of this ? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What's to explain? The Qur'an is very clear about this:

> <sup>4</sup> And those who accuse chaste women and then do not produce four witnesses - lash them with eighty lashes and do not accept from them testimony ever after. And those are the defiantly disobedient
>
> —[Surat An-Nur 4](https://legacy.quran.com/24/4)

The onus is not on you to entertain spurious accusations made against any Muslim woman, the onus is on them to bring forth their witnesses to prove it. And considering A'isha died centuries ago, it seems unlikely that your unnamed acquaintance is in any position to talk, much less in any position to find and present actual witnesses.

A'isha's affair is with Allah now. There is nothing to be gained by besmirching her character after the fact.

As for the hadith itself, it simply states that someone stayed in the house of A'isha; the entire argument beyond that is built on baseless conjecture and speculation. Other hadiths have expounded on this event stating that the guest worried that he had had a nocturnal emission which required cleaning.

Answer (score 2):

I will add to goldPseudo's [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/80809/20218) that the literal hadith only says that the man was hosted as a guest of Aisha. This does **not** mean that he was lodged in the same house where Aisha lived and slept herself, rather she would have arranged accommodation for him somewhere else.

The [hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim:290) says that a slave informed Aisha of what the guest had done and that Aisha sent a message to him inquiring about his action. Similarly a [variant](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:116) of the report mentions that she sent him a blanket and then and he sent it back. All of this indicates that the two were not in the same place.

> ليس معنى أنه كان ضيفاً عندها أنه نام معها في غرفتها إنما في ضيافتها، ولا يلزم أن يكون في منزلها إنما نزل في ضيافتها... كل هذا يدل على أن عائشة ليست بحضرته وليس بحضرتها
>
> <sup>— [Sharah Sunan Tirmidhi](https://shamela.ws/book/23777/741)</sup>